# php - best practice to know whether mail function send mail or not

Tags: php

I am using the below code snippet to send mail via php mail function.

```
$mailsent = mail($to_address, $subject, $message, $headers);

    if ($mailsent) 
        return "mail send";
    else
        return "error";
```

I am checking the boolean in `$mailsent` variable to determine whether the mail is send successfully or not. **Is this the right practice to find the status of mail send by php mail function**. Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

Comment: yes, however, if for `true` case is not mean that the mail %100 is send, but it means that PHP sent that mail...

Answer (score 1):

php.net description of mail function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) states:

*Returns TRUE if the mail was successfully accepted for delivery, FALSE otherwise.
It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination.*

It's the right way to see if the message was accepted to be sent, but not to see if it indeed reached the recipient. You could always check the email you're sending from for a delivery error email.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is right practice,
That is the part of fail safe practice..
You should be checking if mail() returns true or not to determine if mail has been sent successfully.

The mail if relayed from the server, i.e if the mail sent from server it will return true, in addition to that I agree with comment of Akam. it is not necessary that the mail delivered successfully.(this confirms the mail sent.)

I have given a longer snippet that checks on submit only this mail will be sent, you may ignore this..

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $to = "testreceiver@mail.com";
    $subject = "Portfolio Contact";
    $name_field = $_POST['name'];
    $email_field = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $headers = "From: $email_field";
    $body = "From: $name_field\n E-Mail: $email_field\n Message:\n $message";

    $success = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
    if ($success) {
        echo "Mail has been sent!!!!";
        // redirect to thank you page here
    }
    else {
        echo "Message failed";
    }
} else {

echo "Malfunction alert!";

}
?>
```